# ios- sqLite not deleting rows

Tags: ios, sqlite

I am trying to delete all the rows in database for that I wrote following codes ..

```
- (id)init {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *databasePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"dataBase.sqlite3"];
    bool databaseAlreadyExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:databasePath];
    if (!databaseAlreadyExists){
        NSString *databasePathFromApp = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"dataBase" ofType:@"sqlite3"];
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:databasePathFromApp toPath:databasePath error:nil];
    }
    if (sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &_database) == SQLITE_OK){
    }
    return self;
}
-(void)deleteAll{
    NSString *query = @"DELETE FROM user_info";
    sqlite3_stmt *statement = nil;
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_database, [query UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK) {
        NSLog(@"Should delete..");
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    sqlite3_close(_database);
}
```

But when I rebuild the app data data appears. Whats wrong I am doing?

Comment: Did you open the database?

Comment: Yes I did. Wait I am giving the init method.

Comment: Please see the edited question, before calling deleteAll I call init method.

Comment: You are not doing any error checking. Does the "open" succeed? Check all result codes and use `sqlite3_errmsg()` to log errors as needed. Do this on the open, prepare, and step calls.

Comment: if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(statement))
                NSAssert1(0, @"Error while deleting. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
            else
                Nslog(@"Deleted");
check this code write in prepare statement inside .........

Comment: Not necessarily relevant to your question, but you need to perform `self = [super init];` in all `-init` functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never call `sqlite3_step` to actually execute the query.

Also, you close the database in the wrong place. Your close should be done opposite of the open.

Comment: I didn't understand the last line "Your close should be done opposite of the open". Sorry.

Comment: You call open in `init` therefore you should close the database in `dealloc`, not after doing one query.

Comment: I never used sqLite before. I was facing a lot of problem. Thanks a lot.. :)

Comment: I can't decide if I should ask you here, but now I am facing some problem with inserting data in database. Should I post a new question or edit the question?

Comment: Since it is a different problem it should be a new question with all of the appropriate details.

Answer (score 0):

Try a conditional if:

```
if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &deletestmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question.  It looks like you just copied code from another app, but it's very similar to the AP's code in the `deleteAll` method.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, get the database path after that open database

```
NSString *dbPath1=[SqliteManager getDataBasePath];
if (sqlite3_open([dbPath1 UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSLog(@"opened the data base");
    const char *sql = "delete from travels";
if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &deletestmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(deletestmt))
            NSAssert1(0, @"Error while deleting. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        else
            isdeleted=YES;
}
sqlite3_reset(deletestmt); 
sqlite3_close(database);

write in ur method inside..... 
Getting Database Path....
+(NSString *)getDataBasePath
 {  
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory , NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"file Path is %@",documentsDir);
return [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Give ur Sqlite Filename"];    
}
```